# why windows hashes a password?

Tags: windows, security, encryption, hash

There are many operating system and programs that hash passwords for authentication.
Even though they can encrypt the password in many different ways and save it
why do they save the hash of them?
Is the only reason to that question that encrypting them may cause in breaking and decrypting them or there are other reasons?
Thanks for answering in advance

Comment: Are you interested in any OS, or Windows specifically?

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Comment: thanks for your useful response

Answer (score 6):

User credentials (≈passwords) are among the **most valuable assets** stored in an application. They are a prime target for attackers, and as a developer, you want to protect them the best you can.

The principle of *defense in depth* (and common sense) indicates that the more layers of protection you can put around something, the more secure it will be. So as you also mentioned, the purpose of hashing passwords is that even if there is a breach, **an attacker still can't get hold of actual user credentials**.

**The problem with encryption is always key management.** If passwords were stored encrypted, they would need to be decrypted (or the received password encrypted with the same key) to be able to verify a password. For this, the application would need to have access to the key. But that negates the purpose of encryption, an attacker would also have access to the key in case of a breach. (Public key cryptography could make it somewhat more difficult, but essentially the same problem of key management would still persist.)

So in short, only storing salted hashes with an algorithm that is slow enough to prevent brute-force attacks (like PBKDF2 or Bcrypt) is both the simplest and the most secure. (Also note that plain salted hashes are not good enough anymore.)

Comment: @zaph Exactly, hence my note on a slow enough algorithm. I meant things like bcrypt and pbkdf2. :)

Comment: The reason I did not was because the question was about why hashing instead of encryption, and not *how* to do hashing. But you're right, it's better to include this in the answer for future readers. Thanks!

Comment: My issue is the answer is that it went into salting and that is insufficient. Now fixed.

Comment: My POV is to get people to use secure measures that protect the ultinate user and that we really need to promote that. Otherwise we are just helping people jump off bridges which we think is a bad idea.

Comment: There is no difference in our views I think, I agree with you, and you did help to make my answer better, which is great! :) While I did have pbkdf2 and bcrypt in mind when witing the answer, I only wrote "slow enough algorithms", which is very vague and not very helpful for somebody that doesn't know about these. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the need: You define your new password, and then every time you log-in the entered password is hashed and checked against the stored value. This is the simplest and most secure policy to handle this (since no one will be able to re-construct your password from the stored value). Moreover, imagine that you use the same password in several systems. If Windows would enable (regardless how hard it would be) to re-construct your password from what is stored in a Windows system, there would be (quite many) people that would blame Microsoft for security breach on other system (which could derivate into legal actions).

To summarize, simplicity and commercially logical approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually it's for **security** reason.

[**Hash functions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) are usually not revertibles, so even if someone finds out the hashes it would be really difficult for him to find which password generated that hash value.

Obviously you can try with a **dictionary attack** or a **brute force one**, trying to find out the password which generated the hash but it could take a very long time.

Consider that you have a Database with **user** and their **passowrd**, take note that **a lot of people use the very same password everywhere**.

Now immagine if a cracker manages to crack into your DB and finds all the **password written clearly**. That would be a disaster.